# iPhone -> NSNumberFormatter - price without the currency code

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone app and I want to display a price. So I use these lines of code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *price = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[price setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[price setCurrencyCode:@"USD"];
```

What I want is only the price, formatted for the `currencyCode` but in my case without `USD`.
So instead of `30,00 $`, I want to have only `30,00` without `$`.

How can I do this?

Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you're looking to get rid of is the Currency Symbol.

```
[price setCurrencySymbol:@""];
```

Comment: You should also be able to handle international currency symbols using: [price setInternationalCurrencySymbol:@""];

Comment: With da_DA locale it outputs numbers with a space suffix, such as "1.000,00 ".

Comment: use setCurrencyGroupingSeparator: & setCurrencyDecimalSeparator: for locales like Danish etc.

Comment: You can remove the space suffix by setting negative and positiveSuffix.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **setCurrencySymbol** to an empty string which should do the trick:

```
[price setCurrencySymbol:@""];
```

Please keep in mind that this only sets the local currency code and it might not work with foreign currencies.

Comment: But which currrency styling will be used then? Because some countries will write `.` instead of `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it while keeping the correct locale formatting for the symbol:

```
_fmt.positiveFormat = [_fmt.positiveFormat 
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"¤" withString:@""];
_fmt.negativeFormat = [_fmt.negativeFormat 
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"¤" withString:@""];
```

The ¤ character is used in the currency formats for the currency symbol. If you replace the currency symbol as suggested in some of the other answers, the formatter does a US standard format for the number (AFAIK - tested in iOS 4 and 5 in the USA). You'll need to do this replacement after setting the locale for the formatter. Try with the currency code HUF which does not have pennies.